# Taxes refund for French citizen in Canada

Tags: canada, money, tax-refunds

I'm currently in internship in Canada. For every purchase I pay TPS and TVQ (Quebec) taxes.

Is it possible to recover the taxes I paid at the end of my travel?

How I should do?

Comment: If it's possible at all, it will only be possible for items you are taking out of Canada,

Comment: I have no idea about Canadian law on the matter, although I imagine a canadian government website will tell you. But I do know that everywhere I have come across these tax reclaim for visitor schemes, they always only apply to what you buy and take away, not what you buy and use in the country.

Comment: Those close voting as more relevant to expats- the question would (likley) be just as useful to tourists visiting Canada.

Comment: @CMaster in fact it's more useful for tourists, as they are more likely to have items that they have purchased and *not used.*

Comment: @CGCampbell VAT refund schemes require the items to be unused, so they are really only useful for tourists.  If you buy an expensive coat in, for example, Paris, you are more likely to use it before you leave if you're, for example, a student in Paris.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the answer is [no](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/bsnss/tpcs/gst-tps/rbts/vstrs/fctp-eng.html). The informative paragraph:

> If you are a non-resident visitor to Canada, you cannot claim a rebate
>   of the goods and services tax/harmonized sales tax (GST/HST) that you
>   paid for all purchases made in Canada. The visitor rebate program for
>   GST/HST was replaced on April 1, 2007, with the Foreign Convention and
>   Tour Incentive Program (FCTIP). A non-resident visitor to Canada may
>   be eligible to claim a GST/HST rebate on certain purchases related to
>   conventions or for tour packages under the FCTIP.